# Create A Windows 10 App Using HTML, CSS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-10

I'm trying to create a Windows 10 application using HTML CSS and JavaScript... I already have the code saved but I need a way to open it as a .exe file or something... It needs to be a separate file that I can open in a new window.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create an application using web technologies, such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, I will recommend you start looking into the [Electron Framework](https://www.electronjs.org/) which allows you to use web technologies resources for app development.